# C++17 lambda capture *this

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, c++-faq

C++17 will add **copy capture** of this object by value, with [a capture specification of `[*this]`](/a/38060437).

How is this useful? How is it different than capturing `this`? Can't this already be achieved in C++14 with `[tmp = *this]`?

---

Bonus for explaining why [P0018R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0018r3.html) uses `[=, tmp = *this]` instead of `[tmp = *this]` in their example. If they had used `[tmp = *this]`, all the listed downsides of the C++14 solution would be eliminated.

Comment: I guess they simplified the examples too much. Once you add additional local variables or parameters, you'd want to capture them by copy. Then the `[=, ..]` part makes sense (if you don't want to capture them explicitly one-by-one, that is).

Comment: It might be helpful to draw on analogies between non static member functions and other functions, even between C++ and what C++ could have been if, during the history of "C with classes", references came before member functions (`this` is only pointer because there were no references when it was invented).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

How is it useful?  It's useful when you need a copy of `*this` - for example, when `*this` itself is no longer valid by the time the lambda is evaluated.

How is it different from capturing `this`?  It makes a *copy* of the object, so that when the lambda is evaluated, its `this` pointer refers to the copy, rather than to the original object.

Can it be achieved in C++14 with `[tmp = *this]`?  It can, but `[*this]` is more convenient, as code can be moved without prefixing member access with `tmp.`.  Otherwise, especially with `[=, tmp = *this]`, it's possible to accidentally refer to members of the original object when you meant to refer to the copy (particularly if you're in the habit of cut+paste programming).  `[=,*this]` is a safer alternative in this case, as the original object is not accessible from inside the lambda's body (at least, not via the `this` pointer).

Comment: `this` is a scalar rvalue since the first "serious" C++ (only in primitive C++ was it assignable), you can't refer to an object `this`, only to the value of `this`.

Comment: @curiousguy, I'm not sure what your criticism here is.  Have I been ambiguous with terminology somewhere?  I see that I've written "the (original) object" when talking about `*this` - is that giving you problems?

Comment: There is no such thing as the original value of a pointer; a pointer value is a pointer value is a pointer value. "_the original this_" makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks @curiousguy, I think I see what you mean now.  I'll try and think of a clearer way to phrase what I meant. (Time passes).  Better?

Answer (score 5):

Imagine that `*this` is a handle class, which maintains a `shared_ptr` to some shared state.

The shared impl is (for example) a protocol handler state machine.

The handle class is passed through a series of asynchronous handlers, so itself must be copyable. Each handler mutates the shared state.

A strong use case for this might be a protocol handler for use with a custom `asio` service (for example, an `http_protocol_socket`).

`[=, tmp = *this]` will promiscuously capture any variables by value, including, rather dangerously, the `this` pointer itself, as well as specifically capturing `*this` into `tmp`.

In this use case it would be dangerous to inadvertently refer to `this` in the async handler, because it's likely to be a dangling pointer. This is a bug waiting to happen.

`[tmp=*this]` will only capture `*this`.