# Lambda Captures

Tags: c++, lambda, closures

I always get confused by the lambda capture and I don't know if a variable is captured by reference or by value. For instance if I have `[a]` I don't know if `a` is captured by value or by ref.

I think a simple way to get it would be by examples. So let's have one for each of the cases (more if there are more ways of expressing the same thing):

Capture:

- nothing
- all by reference
- all by value
- `r1`, `r2` by reference. Nothing else.
- `v1`, `v2` by value. Nothing else.
- `r1`, `r2` by reference. Rest by value.
- `v1`, `v2` by value. Rest by reference.
- `r1`, `r2` by reference, `v1`, `v2` by value. Nothing else.

Let's completely ignore `this` as that is another bag of worms.

Comment: Do note all the rules are detailed [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture) quite well.

Comment: I am genuinely asking myself each time I write or read a lambda capture and have to search the web. Haven't find a simple clean explanation yet. I think this would be a valuable post here.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, I know, and I still don't know if `[a]` is by ref or value. In truth, I only scan the page. But honestly I don't have neither the will nor the time to read a complex description just when I want to know 1 simple answer. I don't know, maybe it is just me. Regardless, I think a post on SO should exist.

Comment: For sure.  The fact that it isn't here means it should be :-)  I just added the link so if people really want to see the subject in depth they had a good reference.

Comment: Is this meant to go into the [tag:c++-faq]?

Comment: @StoryTeller feel free to add the tag if you think so.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was you intent, and hence the way it's phrased. It certainly looks like it was designed for inclusion :)

Comment: I un-tagged it.

Comment: @Puppy I saw. What was the reason?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
| Capture                                       | Syntax             |
| --------------------------------------------- | ------------------ |
| nothing                                       | []                 |
| all by reference                              | [&]                |
| all by value                                  | [=]                |
| r1, r2 by reference. Nothing else.            | [&r1, &r2]         |
| v1, v2 by value. Nothing else.                | [v1, v2]           |
| r1, r2 by reference. Rest by value.           | [=, &r1, &r2]      |
| v1, v2 by value. Rest by reference.           | [&, v1, v2]        |
| r1, r2 by ref, v1, v2 by value. Nothing else. | [v1, v2, &r1, &r2] |
```

The rule is simple: preceded by an `&`, capture by reference. Name only, capture by value.

Defaults: `=` all by value, `&` all by reference. Things to exclude from "all" use the simple rule above.

---

The full rules can be read on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture).

Answer (score 14):

In short:

```
[]{ }          // do not capture anything
[foo]{ }       // capture `foo` by value
[&foo]{ }      // capture `foo` by reference
[foo, &bar]{ } // capture `foo` by value, `bar` by reference
[=, &foo]{ }   // capture everything by value, `foo` by reference
[&, foo]{ }    // capture everything by reference, `foo` by value
```

In C++14, you also have *generalized lambda captures*:

```
[i=0]{ }  // create closure with `i` data member initialized to `0`
[i=j]{ }  // create closure with `i` data member initialized to `j`
[i{0}]{ } // create closure with `i` data member initialized to `0`
[i{j}]{ } // create closure with `i` data member initialized to `j`

// create closure with `uptr` data member initialized to `std::move(uptr)`
[uptr = std::move(uptr)]{ } 

// create closure with `foo` reference data member initialized to `something`
[&foo = something]{ }
```

---

If you want to conditionally capture either by reference or by value, you can use *generalized lambda captures* to implement some sort of "perfect-forwarding capture": ["capturing perfectly-forwarded objects in lambdas"](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/capturing_perfectly_forwarded_objects_in_lambdas.html).

---

> Let's completely ignore `this` as that is another bag of worms.

```
[this]{ }  // capture `this` by value (the pointer)
[*this]{ } // store a copy of `*this` inside the closure
```

- `[*this]` [was introduced in C++17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637451/c17-lambda-capture-this).
- Note that `[&this]` is [a syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323032/why-cant-i-capture-this-by-reference-this-in-lambda).

Comment: In addition, instead of members capture (in "everything" capture), it is `this` which is captured.

Answer (score 4):

- nothing

  ```
  []
  ```
- all by reference

  ```
  [&]
  ```
- all by value

  ```
  [=]
  ```
- `r1`, `r2` by reference. Nothing else.

  ```
  [&r1, &r2]
  ```
- `v1`, `v2` by value. Nothing else.

  ```
  [v1, v2]
  ```
- `r1`, `r2` by reference. Rest by value.

  ```
  [=, &r1, &r2]
  ```
- `v1`, `v2` by value. Rest by reference.

  ```
  [&, v1, v2]
  ```
- `r1`, `r2` by reference, `v1`, `v2` by value. Nothing else.

  ```
  [&r1, &r2, v1, v2]
  ```