# How to insert elements of Enum type into vector of type uint8_t?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, enums, c++17

I am very new to C++ programming. I want to  insert elements  of type enum into a `vector<uint8_t>` ? ie append all elements of `std::vector <ValType> call` to  `std::vector<uint8_t> bravo`  .Is there any way to do so?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

enum class ValType : uint8_t
{

    Working = 1,
    Failed = 0,
    Freezed = 0

};

int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bravo = {23, 23, 23, 22, 5};
    std::vector<ValType> call;
    bravo.insert(bravo.end(), call.begin(), call.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Live [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/rhBWRuaysD)

I am getting an error while compiling :

```
   In file included from c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\vector:66,
                 from custom.cpp:2:
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_uninitialized.h: In instantiation of '_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*]':
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:333:37:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _ForwardIterator = unsigned char*; _Tp = unsigned char]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\vector.tcc:751:34:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_vector.h:1665:19:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_vector.h:1383:22:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator]'  
custom.cpp:18:17:   required from here
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:138:72: error: static assertion failed: result type must be constructible from value type of input range
  138 |       static_assert(is_constructible<_ValueType2, decltype(*__first)>::value,
      |                                                                        ^~~~~
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_uninitialized.h:138:72: note: 'std::integral_constant<bool, false>::value' evaluates to false
In file included from c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\vector:60,
                 from custom.cpp:2:
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = ValType*; _OI = unsigned char*]':
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:495:30:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = ValType*; _OI = unsigned char*]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:522:42:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a1(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = ValType*; _OI = unsigned char*]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:530:31:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:620:7:   required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char> >]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\vector.tcc:744:16:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_range_insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _ForwardIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::forward_iterator_tag) [with _ForwardIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_vector.h:1665:19:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_dispatch(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator, std::__false_type) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator]'
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_vector.h:1383:22:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::insert(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<ValType*, std::vector<ValType> >; <template-parameter-2-2> = void; _Tp = unsigned char; _Alloc = std::allocator<unsigned char>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::vector<unsigned char>::const_iterator]'  
custom.cpp:18:17:   required from here
c:\program files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\include\c++\11.2.0\bits\stl_algobase.h:385:25: error: cannot convert 'ValType' to 'unsigned char' in assignment
  385 |               *__result = *__first;
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone please show me the correct way of doing this?

Comment: On an unrelated question, why are you using the non-standard and non-portable `__uint8_t` instead of the standard `uint8_t`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude ..Sorry the online one had __uint8_t not uint8_t..so I put the same.you can assume uint8_t

Comment: Include `<cstdint>` which defines the standard integer types.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can an enum class be converted to the underlying type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589417/can-an-enum-class-be-converted-to-the-underlying-type)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::transform` with your own conversion function.

```
std::vector<uint8_t> bravo = {23, 23, 23, 22, 5};
std::vector<ValType> call;

std::transform(bravo.cbegin(), bravo.cend(), std::back_inserter(call),
               [](uint8_t a) { return static_cast<ValType>(a); });
```

Comment: Getting error 

` error: 'bravo' is not captured
                     { return static_cast<ValType>(bravo[a]); });`

Comment: Code :

#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>

enum class ValType : uint8_t
{
    Working = 1,
    Failed = 0,
    Freezed = 0
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> bravo = {23, 23, 23, 22, 5};
    std::vector<ValType> call;
    std::transform(bravo.cbegin(), bravo.cend(), std::back_inserter(call), [](uint8_t a)
                   { return static_cast<ValType>(bravo[a]); });
    return 0;
}

Comment: Check here https://onlinegdb.com/HRO8yJdIp .. Can you please show the correct way?

Comment: @SenorMaldona updated the answer. Now it should compile

Comment: @SenorMaldona https://onlinegdb.com/hWBePAJRy

Comment: Murat Sagdicoglu..Thanks..But  I guess your code does the opposite what I want. I want to append all elements from call vector into bravo vector ...see here  https://onlinegdb.com/crYzDzbRm

Comment: For eg If `std::vector<uint8_t> bravo = {23, 23, 23, 22, 5}` and 
    `std::vector<ValType> call = {7}` . then append elements of call into bravo.Hence bravo becomes `{23, 23, 23, 22, 5 , 7}`

Comment: Then, you should do the opposite. See:  https://onlinegdb.com/A17a5-Tuj

Comment: @SenorMaldona As an aside, this is the reason why it didn't compile first time, when your lambda needs to access variables from outside the scope of lambda, the variable needs to be explicitly captured, only then you'll have access to variables outside of lamda scope, refer this link for more, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46809901/lambda-captures

Comment: @ÖzgürMuratSağdıçoğlu what if I need to add only one elements ( not vector ) ?kind  of push_back(). ie `std::vector<uint8_t> bravo .push_back(callelement)`  callelement is of type ValType...

Comment: If I heard you right, If you want to do it for a single element, you can go do static_cast on the argument to push_back

Comment: @Rajesh How should I do it correctly there are two ways
1) `ValType Types = static_cast<ValType>(45);
    bravo.push_back(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<ValType>>(Types)); `

2) `bravo.push_back(static_cast<uint8_t>(Types));`

Both are the giving correct output. Can you please tell me which one is better?

Comment: @SenorMaldona I feel you'd be better off with option 2, since it is easy to read, less verbose, conveys the intent clearly

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in e.g. [this scope enumeration reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum#Scoped_enumerations):

> **There are no implicit conversions from the values of a scoped enumerator to integral types**, although `static_cast` may be used to obtain the numeric value of the enumerator.

<sub>[Emphasis mine]</sub>

So while it might look like inheritance when defining the enumeration, it's not. The type `ValType` is a completely separate type, which can't be converted to or from any other plain integer type, not even the one used as the enumeration base-type.

That means you can't simply copy from a vector of `ValType` elements to a vector of `uint8_t` elements. If you need to do such a copy you must implement your own conversion (using e.g. `static_cast`), perhaps using [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) and an [back insert iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator).

Comment: Thanks.. `If you need to do such a copy you must implement your own conversion (using e.g. static_cast), perhaps using std::transform and an back insert iterator.` can you please show me how to do this  with my problem?